# The contents of a loaded div doesn't appear from a loaded HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm developing a single-page web app. What I did is that I have a main page `index.html` where I have all the skeleton of the app but I have in the `body` a `div` that i use to load the contents of the page that I want to show. In the loaded page I have a `div` whose contents need to loaded as well. The issue is that the contents of the second div doesn't appear and I can't figure out why.

I think you would need an example to better understand.

I have two html files: `index.html` and `browse.html`.

First here is `browse.html`:

```
<div id="browse_contents">
</div>
```

Finally  here is `index.html`:

```
<html>
<head>
//load jquery

<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

$("#browse_page").load("browse.html")
$("#browse_contents").html("<p>The contents.</p>")

});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="browse_page"></div>
</body>
</html
```

So the problem is that "The contents." doesn't appear and I can't figure out why!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, `#browse_contents` doesn't exist in the DOM when you are attempting to change its HTML.

`.load()` is asynchronous, which is why it and other jQuery AJAX methods come with a callback parameter; a function to call when the request is complete:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#browse_page").load("browse.html", function(){
        $("#browse_contents").html("<p>The contents.</p>");
    });
});
```